# Артефакты на экране ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, артефакты

Сегодня поставил себе на компьютер  Ubuntu 20. После установки всех программ решил поиграть в TESO, поиграл минут 10 где то, игра зависла и весь экран высыпало артефактами, я перезагрузился, все Окей минут 5 и снова все виснет и артефакты. Я попробовал загрузиться с флэшки и переустановить дистрибутив, все время установки ни одного артефакта или подвисания, но после перезагрузки, как начала грузиться ОС все остановилось на чёрном экране и снова все в артефактах.
Что это такое, не видео карта же, если при загрузке с флэшки все Окей.

Comment: можно попробовать поотключать все шашечки. Или запустить openbox, например.

Comment: ну это похоже на битую память видеокарты, проблемы которой проявляются при нагрузке(нагреве). Ну или еще триста причин.

Comment: обратитесь в службу поддержки этой игры и уверяю вас, они пошлют вас лесом, поскольку эта игра никогда не разрабатывалась под убунту. здесь только 2 варианта - играть на той платформе, под которую игра была написана, либо наплевать на разработчиков игр, которым наплевать на вас.

Comment: Выяснилось что дело не в игре, и ни в чем таком, я пробовал перестанавливать системы и все работает нормально, до того момента пока я не поставлю последнюю версию проприетарного драйвера. И после перезагрузки начинаются артефакты, на mint у меня подобных проблем не было

Comment: Не используйте проприетарные решения.

Comment: Да, это оказался единственный выход